# ¿Como puedo protegerme con un objeto(escudo) del impacto de otro objeto(cohete)?

Tags: unity3d

Lo que quiero conseguir es activar un escudo con colliders o triggers, con el boton izquierdo del raton "Fire 2" cuando un cohete me impacta y no me destruya.

Comment: Hola! Puedes pegar el codigo en vez de postear una imagen? Saludos

Comment: podrías probar algo sencillo. * En el caso de que estés usando estados, puedes decirle que si estas con el escudo activado, el daño no se refleje en la vida y viceversa.

Comment: Gracias @IPinchol pero mi pregunta ya se resolvió, gracias de todas formas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuponiendo que el cohete se lanza correctamente, que es un rigidbody al que le das impulso y que el escudo es un objeto que está referenciado desde el panel Inspector, el planteamiento de la clase `quitarshieldlollevaelescudo` me parece correcto, pero veo algunos errores que te impedirán ejecutar el código. Para empezar, tienes un campo público llamado `escudo`, pero luego, aparentemente, te refieres a él por el nombre `shield`. Además, te falta un paréntesis en esa instrucción if.

```
public class quitarshieldlollevaelescudo : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject escudo;    

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetButton("Fire2"))
            escudo.SetActive(true);
        // Te falta desactivarlo cuando no pulsan el botón
        else
            escudo.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Ahora, deberías añadirle un script al escudo e implementar el método `OnCollisionEnter()` para destruir el cohete cada vez que colisiona con él. Agrégale un tag "missile" al prefab del cohete y haz algo así:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
{       
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "missile") 
    { 
        // TODO: Activas efecto de partículas y sonido de explosión
        // Destruyes el misil
        Destroy(col.gameObject);
    }     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Que tal si mientras el click secundario esta presionado, desvías el daño causado? osea, cuando el cohete impacta con el player, este genera un daño, el cual esta directamente relacionado con la vida del player, si el player tiene presionado el click secundario, este daño deja de estar relacionado con la vida del player, y simplemente hace la accion de explotar, no tengo unity instaldo en este momento asique solo puedo ayudarte con teoria :)

Comment: Bueno también es verdad que el algoritmo de la vida del player puede ser la solución pero aun no me he metido en ello porque no conozco ese algoritmo. De todos gracias por tu aportación, aun así, el escudo impediría que te hiciera daño o te quitara parte de la vida no se como hacerlo.